# Creating index with 'whitespace' analyzer

Tags: lucene, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm trying to initialise a basic index that will use the whitespace analyser and I just want to confirm I'm doing this correctly

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "whitespace": {
          "type": "whitespace",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}'
```

When I do this I get

```
{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
```

but if I then go to `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/` and on the *Actions* drop-down choose *Test Analyzer* with the text "this is a test", it only returns one token, "test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct analyzer test will default to standard analyzer. Instead write a custom_analyzer and test that on the index using analyze api. The analyzer you have written is not a custom one or default. You can set an analyzer to default analyzer also.

Set whitespace analyzer as default analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "whitespace",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}'
```

Set whitespace analyzer as custom analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "myAnalyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}'
```

How to test them??

Testing default analyzer on a specific index:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?text=this+is+a+test'
```

Testing custom analyzer on a specific index:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=myAnalyzer' -d 'this is a test'
```